# In a list of tuples, find a match if a certain field is set

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[
 (36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0), 
 (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3), 
 (140, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 34, 1), 
 (141, 0, 6.35533332824707, 5.926896095275879, 22, 2)
]
```

I'd like to iterate through the list, and if the second field in the tuple is '1', then I'd like to find anything that matches the first field, and return both tuples as a new tuple (or other data structure; doesn't have to be a tuple) within a list of matches.  So in this example, the output would be something like:

```
[(
 (36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0),
 (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3)
)]
```

I'm at a bit of a loss where to start with this without getting into a very slow O(n^n) sort of situation.

Comment: the tuples are consecutive? I mean when you find the 1, you just return the current tuple AND the next one?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, not necessarily, at least currently.  Though perhaps there is a way to sort the list so that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to process the list of tuples, not assuming that the list is properly sorted.

- first sort the list of tuples according to first value and second value compared to 1 (to issue a boolean), so tuples are "grouped" by first "column", and 1 occuring first in the list of tuples. Sort is not `O(n**2)`, probably `O(log(n)*n)`
- then compose a generator expression using `groupby` to group tuples according to the first value (second value "1" still is first when grouped)
- finally filter out groups where 1 isn't present

Last steps are `O(n)`. Here's the code:

```
from itertools import groupby

tuple_list = [
 (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3),
 (140, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 34, 1),
 (141, 0, 6.35533332824707, 5.926896095275879, 22, 2),
 (36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0),
]

ones_first = (sorted(tuple_list,key=lambda r : (r[0],r[1]!=1)))
tuples = (tuple(x for x in y) for _,y in groupby(ones_first,key=lambda r : r[0]))

with_ones = tuple(filter(lambda r : r[0][1]==1,tuples))
print(with_ones)
```

result:

```
(((36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0), (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3)),)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=[
 (36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0), 
 (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3), 
 (140, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 34, 1), 
 (141, 0, 6.35533332824707, 5.926896095275879, 22, 2)
]
```

Here's a one line nested for loop list comprehension:

```
out=[y for x in lst if x[1]==1 for y in lst if y[0]==x[0]]
print(out)
[(36, 1, 2908.8037109375, 1835.6429443359375, 17, 0), (36, 0, 184187.125, 148323.234375, 55, 3)]
```

If you have a lot of tuples in `lst` then there would be faster ways of searching for the result than this.